# Python - export result value to text file

Tags: python

Python newb here - tried a few things I found on google but it hasn't worked, perhaps I'm phrasing what I want to do incorrectly. I have an IRC bot that runs the following after a game:

```
def finish(attacker,defender,winner):
    if winner == attacker:
        kick(defender,"banned")
    else:
        kick(attacker,"banned")
```

What i would like to do is take the winner value and export it into a .txt file, along with a counter on how many times they ended up as the "winner". as i said, i tried a few things i found on google and tried to make sure of some other bots that do similar things but it doesn't seem to work (As the methods I'm trying appear to be more complicated than the simple export I'm doing).

Comment: So what I believe you want to do is read the file in update the counter than export it bacK?

Comment: This code is not even valid; it needs tabs

Comment: @codequestioneer: For indentation the code doesn't need tabs, it needs spaces (according to PEP-8).

Comment: What I want it to do is take the value in "winner" and put that into a text file, along with a counter. So for example, if "user1" is the winner, it puts user1 - 1 into a text file

Comment: Insufficient information provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are 2 options here.  Do you mean you want a file that is basically a log of all the games and who won?  This is the easier option.  The file would look like:

```
1/1/14 00:00:01 Player 1 won 3 games
1/1/14 00:01:01 Player 2 won 5 games
1/1/14 00:04:05 Player 1 won 5 games
```

Or... you might want a file that only contains totals:

```
Player 1 has won a total of 8 games.
Player 2 has won a total of 5 games.
```

To do the first option, you just need something simple like:

```
score_filehandle = open("filename.txt","w+")
# And then when a game ends:
score_filehandle.write(" ".join([current_time, player_id, "won", games_won, "games"]) + "\n")
```

To do the second one is much more complicated, and is probably best handled using sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code if it helps:

```
import random
import csv

count = 0
with open('sample.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['count', 'token']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    while count < 100000:
        strRand = ''.join(random.sample(map(chr, range(48, 57) + range(65, 90) + range(97, 122)), 24))
        writer.writerow({'count': count, 'token': strRand})
        count = count + 1
```